# How to make a C# template with different attributes

Tags: c#, templates, service, web, attributes

I am creating a web service for different clients. So I have 3 classes for 3 different client types:

Type 1:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapRpcMethod(Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
public string databaseConnectionInfo()
{
  return WSExecute.Executer.databaseConnectionInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
}
```

Type 2:

```
[WebMethod]
public string databaseConnectionInfo()
{
  return WSExecute.Executer.databaseConnectionInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
}
```

Type 3:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument databaseConnectionInfo()
{
  return this.convert(WSExecute.Executer.databaseConnectionInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current));
}
```

As you can see functions are almost the same – they all call the same working class except that they are different in attirbutes (Type1 vs. Type2) or call one additional function which only converts string to XMLDocument.

QUESTION:
How can C# or Visual Studio help me create some kind of template or something to manage that. The problem I am facing is that there will be more than 100 functions and the interface will be managed by different programmers which are not all good in C#. So they will forgot to write “same” code in three different classes / sources :(

Does anybody know how to solve problem Type1 vs. Type2 (forget about Type 3). Type1 and 2 are really the same source except:
1.  Class name is different
2.  Every function in Type1 has an additional SoapRpcMethod attribute

For now I am solving this by using pre-processor (my own program) which produces 3 sources from 1 source and then call C# compiler. It works but it is clumsy and is hard to understand for somebody not so familiar with C# programming. Web Service is used for accessing Oracle Servers so c# web service is only a façade and there is no application logic in web service only calls to PL/SQL procedures and so c# Web Service is managed by Oracle Programmers not familiar with Windows/c#...

TIA
Matjaz

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem you're trying to address is code duplication - you should check out the [Template design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) . That way, people wouldn't just 'forget' to write the redundant code they're supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that they have to write ONE line of code in THREE different classes. I have used all patterns that I can and this lives me with 1 line pre function.

But this line must be written into three different classes which produces three different webServices for three different types of clients. Everything is almost the same except attributes on functions in each class 